# product spotted as article in google structured data

Tags: seo, wordpress, structured-data

i have fixed all errors and warnings of my website with Schema & Structured Data For WP.

problem is that product pages defined as article so i got bad rank.
i'm not very familar with coding.

is there any simple way for fix this problem?

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
```

[google structure data tester](https://shorturl.at/bgxDH)

[image: google structure data tester]

> please tell me if need more information.

Answer (score 1):

What plugins are you using?  Some plugins like Yoast will automatically use the Article schema for any blog post.  I'm guessing that you probably have another plugin that is also adding schema objects to your content.

Try disabling all of your other WordPress plugins and rerun Google's Schema tester.  Then add the plugins back in one at a time, and re run your test until you discover which plugins are adding what.

Comment: yes  i use of yoast seo and [schema and structured data](https://wordpress.org/plugins/schema-and-structured-data-for-wp/). yoast seo do not support all types of shema, right? should i remove other one? thanks for response

Comment: @sammy, there are other ways to remove Yoast schema, including plugins and/or code options.  Google for WP plugin to remove Yoast schema.  Your Schema plugin may also have the option built in.